# Need to connect a Java client to a Cpp server using TCP and OpenSSL

Tags: java, c++

I have looked everywhere and noone seems to ba able to explain how to connect a Java client to a Cpp server using TCP and OpenSSL. The connection I need to make is over TCP. This Java program will also be an applet.  I am concerned about security issues so I need to use OpenSSL.  I would appreciate a responce.  If it could please be as simple as possible and include all the Java packages and Cpp libraries listed.  I will show you what I have so far. All my source should be able to compile right away.  I'm listing both Cpp and java source.

```
/*******************
 * Java Client     *
 *******************/
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;


public class gaia_applet extends Applet {

  int width, height;

  public static void init(String[] args) throws IOException {

    SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("localhost", 6001);

    }

 }

 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  g.setColor(Color.blue);
  g.drawString("My Applet",30,180);
 }


}
/*****************
 * CPP Server    *
 *****************/
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ssleay32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "libeay32.lib")

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define PORT "6001"

void init_OpenSSL(void);

using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 BIO *acc, *client;

// init_OpenSSL();

 acc = BIO_new_accept(PORT);
 if (!acc)
 cout << "Error creating server socket";

 if (BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0)
 cout << "Error binding server socket";

while(1) {

 cout << "Socket OK!";

 if (BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0)
 cout << "Error accepting connection";
 client = BIO_pop(acc);
 cout << "New connection!";
 }

 BIO_free(acc);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Does the java code successfully connect to the C++ application? Are you unsure how to structure the communications between the client and server?

Comment: What happens when you run your code, what is the actual **problem** you encounter? If you are running into problems, have you tried reducing your scope first, like making a simple TCP connection between the applications, and then introducing SSL into the mix?

Comment: No I haven't tested it with straight TCP/IP sockets but am pretty sure the above code should work right out of the box. All I need is a simple TCP/IP OpenSSL connection between A Cpp server and a Java Applet client on the same machine

Comment: The problem I am having is I run both programs on the same server and no connection is made

Answer (score 1):

Java applets are only capable of opening sockets to the server from which they were originally requested. All other socket requests will fail unless you sign your applet.  It is unclear if this is your problem or not since we don't know where your applet resides.

Comment: The applet resides on localhost (the same computer as the server) I don't think I need a certificate, do I?  I heard since it is not fully conifgured as an encrypted socket I wouldn't have to worry about certificates.

Comment: I wouldn't have to configure it yet that is

Comment: No I haven't tested it with straight TCP/IP sockets but am pretty sure the above code should work right out of the box.  All I need is a simple TCP/IP OpenSSL connection between A Cpp server and a Java Applet client on the same machine